# subpattern regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to retrieve all matches on a string with one regex:

```
var str = "lorem -req=aaa(opt:3,m:2),bbb(opt:4) ipsum ",
res = str.match(/.../); //  ????
```

what to use to obtain something like

```
[
  ['aaa', 'opt:3,m:2'],
  ['bbb', 'opt:4']
]
```

is it possible without using a function?

Comment: "And I tried".... please add. *is it possible without using a function* implies you tried to write some function.

Comment: I made many attempts ... btw 
**I' m not asking for the solution...**  
just want to know if it can be done without a function. Thank You very much

Comment: At this point, why speak about a function at all? You need to clearly understand  - and share with us - the specifications. Can the parentheses be nested?

Comment: Yes, it can be done without a function. It will, however, probably require a loop. Certainly the simple, reasonable way of doing it does. To answer properly in any real way needs much more specific information. Are there only ever two instances? What defines what you're matching? For that matter, why would a function be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
[=,]([^\(]*)\(([^\)]*)\)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/LwHozA/2)

Group 1, and 2 contains your matches

Comment: Thank You very much, still I need to manage the -req... btw this is a nice starting point